# Customizing Layout toolbar of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, toolbar

Can I rearrange the elements within the Layout toolbar?

I want to put the Align Edge tool elsewhere, away from Shared features, like at the end of the Toolbar

I have tried customize, and I cannot seem to be able to reorder this Toolbar.

Comment: Customize is how you do this. What precisely did you try?  I have removed the 10.5 version from your title because I believe 10.4.1 is the latest release.

Comment: Tried to physically relocate the order of the toolbar, with Customize  and I cannot

Comment: @RalphJaggi please confirm you're talking about the Layout toolbar (as shown in the first image of my answer below) as I do not have the Align Edge or Shared Features buttons on my Layout toolbar

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the Align Edge or Shared Features buttons on my Layout toolbar

[image]

However you can move buttons on any toolbar by using Customize > Customize Mode

[image]

Once you're in Customize Mode (you'll have the Customize window open) you can move/edit/add/delete buttons on any toolbars, whether they are your own custom added ones or standard toolbars that come with ArcMap.  While Customize window is open, just click and drag any buttons you want to move, and release them in the position/toolbar you want.  To create separators just drag the button slightly further to the right.

In this screenshot I am dragging the Fixed Zoom In button and dropping it between the Toggle Draft Mode and Focus Data Frame buttons

[image]

[image]